# Tableau - Using Lookup and Grand Total in calculation formula

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to using Tableau, and I am trying to make a calculation row below grand total.

The row will take will take the count of null values of each month from the grand total.

I presume the best way would be to use the lookup function(Contains "Null").  Or could I use an offset ?

I would appreciate some help with the syntax of the calculation field.

[TableauTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNmc8.png)

[Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNiA3.jpg)

Comment: which calculation you are trying Row or Column?

Comment: I need a calculation row beneath the grand total @Siva

Comment: what exactly you want to see in that row, because as I see you are already getting count of NULL

Comment: I want to calculate the Grand Total - Count(Null) in the row beneath the grand total.

Comment: @Siva For example the new row for the first column would calculate 1,401-1299.

Comment: ok got it, give me sometime will post answer

Comment: No problem, Thank you @Siva

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Best way I think of is by using 2 sheets and then combining those in tableau dashboard.

You don't need to use LookUp function instead you can use simple If statement and then subtract that value from grand total.

Take new sheet and create a calculation field and write below code:

Assuming you are taking measure as `Sales` else replace the your measure at the sales part.

```
Total(SUM(Sales))-Sum(IF TimetoConnect="NULL" then sales end)
```

Create the same columns for this row as you created for parent sheet

Now go to dashboard and then take container as floating and place sheet one below one

Comment: So yes I have figured out by doing the above that this is not possible unless I am missing something here.  I have completed the two sheets in a new dashboard below, but that wont allow be to carry out another calculation so It looks like Tableau lacks this functionality.

Comment: another calculation means?

Comment: I want to get the figures in Sheet 2.1 represent as a percentage of the Grand Total in 2.0.  I have updated my post below with a snapshot of my dashboard with the two new sheets.  It's a very easy calculation, but I am doubtful Tableau has the functionality to create a calculation between two different sheets.

Comment: Also update what is required, I think you have just updated what you have done... unable to understand your requirement clearly